# Time Series Prediction for Variable-Length Input with Fixed Sampling Period

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python, keras, curve-fitting

I'm working on a time series prediction task where I need to predict the parameters (amp, phase, freq, offset) that best fit a variable-length input series. The samples are always at the same period.

Here are the key details:

Input Data:

- Variable-length series.
- Consistent sampling period.
  Parameters to Predict:
- Amplitude (amp)
- Phase
- Frequency (freq)
- Offset

I'm looking for guidance on the following aspects:

1.Model Selection:
What kind of model architecture or approach is suitable for predicting these parameters from a variable-length time series?
2. Input Representation:
How should I represent the input data for the model, considering the variable length of the series?
3. Loss Function:
What kind of loss function should I use for training the model to predict these parameters?
4. Implementation Considerations:
Any specific considerations or best practices when implementing such a model?

I've already tried with LSMTM NN with masking layer:

```
   1 Model: "sequential" 
   2 _________________________________________________________________ 
   3  Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param # 
   4 ================================================================= 
   5  masking (Masking)           (None, None, 1)           0 
   6  lstm (LSTM)                 (None, None, 64)          16896 
   7  lstm_1 (LSTM)               (None, 64)                33024 
   8  dense (Dense)               (None, 4)                 260 
   9 =================================================================
```

But test are not giving me good results. More precisely: I trained the net giving input series with length variable between 5 and 30; results seems acceptable when giving input data of length around 20 and 25.

I'm looking for insights and suggestions from the community to improve the accuracy and efficiency of my predictions.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

---

screenshot of ground truth, samples and nn output:
[image]